# Dynamically Created Button Appears Over Another One - Python Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tkinter

I have a problem. I dynamically created buttons using a class. Each button is stored in a list, so I can use them later by indexing them. I am having trouble placing/displaying the buttons, though. When I create one button, it shows up perfectly. When I create another one, for some reason it appears over the first one. Help to fix this would be appreciated. Thanks!

Here is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('800x600')
placeX = 20
placeY = 20
bl = []

def direction(type_):
    pass

class SideBar():
    def __init__(self, name):
        global window
        global placeX
        global placeY
        global bl
        self.name = name
        self.placeX = placeX
        self.placeY = placeY
        self.bl = bl
        self.bl.append(self.name)
        print(self.bl)

    def create_folder(self, index):
        self.bl[index] = tk.Button(window, text = self.name, command = lambda: direction(self.name))
        self.bl[index].config(height = 3, width = 6)
        self.bl[index].place(x = self.placeX, y = self.placeY)
        self.placeY += 100


Computer = SideBar('Computer')
Documents = SideBar('Documents')

Computer.create_folder(0)
Documents.create_folder(1)

window.mainloop()
```

I think the problem is somewhere in the create_folder function.

Comment: The buttons appear in the same place because that's exactly what you're telling them to.  Each `SideBar` you create gets the same `placeX`/`placeY` values from the global variables, which are never changed.  The `self.placeY += 100` line has absolutely no effect, because you never use that instance variable again (`Computer` and `Documents` have their own independent copies of it).

Comment: This is why a widget should never place itself. Have the caller place the widget wherever it wants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *probably* meant to use a *class variable* as opposed to an instance attribute. A class variable holds the data shared among *all* instances of a class, in fact, it can have a value as long as there's a class definition. Whereas an instance attribute can have values specific to a singular instance of a class, typically in the format `self.attribute`.

The way you are trying to use `self.placeY` fits the typical use of class variable. Remove:

```
self.placeY = placeY
```

add:

```
class SideBar():
    ...
    placeY = placeY #assign global placeY's value to Sidebar.placeY
    ...
```

finally, replace:

```
self.placeY += 100
```

with:

```
SideBar.placeY += 100
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating two different instances of a class. Both have their own local variable. Create one instance and use something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('800x600')
placeX = 20
placeY = 20
bl = []

def direction(type_):
    pass

class SideBar():
    def __init__(self):
        global window
        global placeX
        global placeY
        global bl
        self.name = []
        self.placeX = placeX
        self.placeY = placeY
        self.bl = []
        self.bl.append(self.name)

    def create_folder(self, index, name):
        self.name.append(name)
        self.bl.append(tk.Button(window, text = self.name[-1], command = lambda: direction(self.name)))
        self.bl[-1].config(height = 3, width = 6)
        self.bl[-1].place(x = self.placeX, y = self.placeY)
        self.placeY += 100


side_bar = SideBar()
#Documents = SideBar('Documents')

side_bar.create_folder(0, 'Computer')
side_bar.create_folder(1, 'Documents')

window.mainloop()
```